# Set OSM config options using API and not the global config file

Tags: c++, gdal

When reading OSM files using GDAL, the fields that are read are defined in `osmconf.ini`, and if I want that certain tags don't appear within the `other_tags` then I need to add them to the `attributes` value in the corresponding sections.

This works fine, but is not really portable, so my questions is, is there a ways to define the settings saved in `osmconf.ini` in a portable way per project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the [CPLSetConfigOption](https://gdal.org/1.11/cpl__conv_8h.html#aa0cd1a68fe4f2fc7874cd2da605c36ce) function, and store the config file in current working directory:

```
CPLSetConfigOption("OSM_CONFIG_FILE", "osmconf.ini");
```